# Any way to run an ESLint rule on whole project like Run Inspection by Name in WebStorm

Tags: eslint, webstorm, typescript-eslint

"Run Inspection by Name" lets me run any code analysis rule in WebStorm and find all violators throughout the whole monorepo, but there doesn't seem to be any ESLint integration. Currently, I have to open individual files to find out if there are any lint problems and then I can auto fix them. Is there any way to do the same kind of thing as "Run Inspection by Name" but with ESLint rules?

I know I can use the CLI ESLint, but I'd rather go to each file in WebStorm and fix it instead of have ESLint do it from the CLI, that is just too much automation for me given that this project has not been fully ESLint compliant ever and there are thousands of violations. Auto-fixing *will* break stuff.

Comment: Are you asking how to run a **single specific** ESLint rule via WebStorm ... or just the ESLint at all (I mean, only ESLint integration, whatever config it uses). Because you can do the later -- use that "Run Inspection by Name" and select ESLint there.... What ESLint runs it's then up to how you configured ESLint in WebStorm...

Comment: You may also use the "Inspect Code..." action -- just have the separate Inspection Profile where only ESLint inspection is enabled.

Comment: @LazyOne running ESLint would be sufficient, although I only care about 1 rule right now. I can adjust the config if I have to. I swear I tried this before, I must have thought it was a config setting or something and ignored it lol

Comment: Can you make your first comment an answer and I'll mark it? @LazyOne

Answer (score 1):

Integration with all linters (be it for JavaScript/TypeScript or PHP etc.) is done via Inspections. This way the IDE can show linting results as errors/warnings right in the Editor.

Because it's an inspection, it can be run using that `Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name...` action -- just select the ESLint there (as long as it is enabled of course):

[image]

Another option is to use `Code | Inspect Code...` and make and select there a **custom Inspection Profile** that will include only desired inspections (e.g. ESLint only or ESLint and a few most important/handy for you inspections).

[image]

The rest is up to how the ESLint tool is configured: to have only specific rules (a separate config file perhaps?). This is done at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, we currently have ~20,000 violations so being able to focus on knocking out easy fixes is helpful